# Running Datalust/Seq on Ubuntu, can't rich the UI

Tags: networking, ubuntu, port-forwarding, nginx

I just installed Seq database (v2022.1) on my Ubuntu (v20.04.4, it is a Server, not WSL) using it's official docker image (datalust/seq), following the steps described here: [Getting Started with Docker](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/getting-started-with-docker).

The only diffrence is I want the UI port to be 8080 (rather default 80), as there is already a Mail service running on my server:

```
PH=$(echo 'myPassword' | sudo docker run --rm -i datalust/seq config hash)
sudo docker run \
  --name seq \
  -d \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y \
  -e SEQ_FIRSTRUN_ADMINPASSWORDHASH="$PH" \
  -v /var/seq:/data \
  -p 8080:80 \   ----> difference is here
  -p 5341:5341 \
  datalust/seq
```

The container is running normally and I can get Seq index html page ON THE SERVER:
`curl http://localhost:8080`

On my local machine, on the other hand, I can't see the Seq UI. heading to `http://{my-server-address}` leads me to Mail service index page, but trying to reach `http://{my-server-address}:8080`, I get connection time out.

Both 8080 and 5341 (seq ingestion-only) ports are open:

```
ufw status

Status: active

   To                     Action      From
   --                     ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5341                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5341 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I even tried to redirect a path to port, using nginx config file:

```
server {
    location /seq {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

but problem still exists.

Comment: With the nginx config, can you try referring to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`? Alternatively, in Docker, can you try publishing the port on all interfaces with `-p 0.0.0.0:8080:80`?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke thank you. `127.0.0.1` made no difference. I'm new to docker. how should I publishing the port on all interfaces?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show how you're publishing the port currently on port 8080? I.e. show the full `docker` command you're using to get the database running. Also, are you using an Ubuntu server, or is it Ubuntu running in WSL?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I've edited the question. I'm using a server, not WSL.

Comment: Ok, so what if you try my suggested `-p 0.0.0.0:8080:80` instead of `-p 8080:80`?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke based on your hints, I tried this yesterday. no change :(

Comment: Ok, best to include in your question what you've tried so far. What do the nginx logs say, when you try to redirect `/seq` to `http://localhost:8080`? Can you check from the client, if port 8080 is open on the server, e.g. [using telnet](https://kb.synology.com/en-me/DSM/tutorial/Whether_TCP_port_is_open_or_closed)?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Thank you for leading me this far. telnet shows the port is not open, so the next option is to call Host Provider !

Comment: Ok, calling the hoster is certainly an option, but reverse proxying through nginx should work. Have you checked the nginx logs?